# Generating a variety of magic circles

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

[image: Magic circle example]

Magic circles are a visualization of ritual magic which includes symmetries, obscure symbols, circles, parallel lines and polygons. While such circles are probably laid out by hand, it should be possible to create magic circles in (La)TeX. Magic circles can have a wide variety of styles so don't feel tied to this one.

#### How can you create a variety of magical circles in (La)Tex?

This could be accomplished by an existing package, a domain specific language or something generated randomly.

Comment: It's my first time asking a question here. Please give me feedback.

Comment: Read the TikZ or PSTricks documentation for about 3 hours or maybe 24 hours and finally you can create it.

Comment: With MetaPost + LuaLaTeX (for alchemical and CJK characters), it looks quite easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example to get you started.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{marvosym}  % star signs
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Draw two large circles
        \draw (0, 0) circle [radius=10cm];
        \draw (0, 0) circle [radius=10.5cm];
        % Draw double square
        \draw (45:10) rectangle (-135:10);
        \draw (45:9.8) rectangle (-135:9.8);
        % Other two double squares are the same but rotated by 30 and 60 degrees
        \draw[rotate=30] (45:10) rectangle (-135:10);
        \draw[rotate=30] (45:9.8) rectangle (-135:9.8);
        \draw[rotate=60] (45:10) rectangle (-135:10);
        \draw[rotate=60] (45:9.8) rectangle (-135:9.8);
        % Circle within squares
        \draw (0, 0) circle[radius=6.929cm]; % radius = 9.8*sin(45)
        % Star
        \node[star, star point height=3.5cm, minimum size=2*6.929cm, draw] at (0, 0) {};
        % Double circle within star
        \draw (0, 0) circle [radius=3.41cm];  % radius by trial and error
        \draw (0, 0) circle [radius=3.1cm];
        % Radial lines in double circle every 10 degrees
        \foreach \a in {0, 10, ..., 350} {
            \draw (\a:3.1) -- (\a:3.41);
        }
        % star signs every 30 degrees
        \foreach \i in {1, 2, ...,12} {
            \node at (\i*30:9.3) {\Huge\Zodiac{\i}};  % \Huge makes the star signs larger
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The two packages used here where [Tikz](https://texample.net//media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf) for most of the drawing and [Marvosym](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/marvosym) for the star signs.

Two coordinate systems are useful here. [Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) in Tikz are given by `(a, b)` whereas [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) are given as `(angle:radius)` which corresponds to the Cartesian coordinates `(radius*cos(angle), radius*sin(angle))`

The key tikz commands used for this drawing are as follows:

```
\draw (a, b) -- (c, d);
```

which draws a straight line from `(a, b)` to `(c, d)`.
\draw (a, b) circle [radius=xcm];
which draws a circle centred at `(a, b)` with radius `x` measured in centimetres.

```
\draw (a, b) rectangle (c, d);
```

which draws a rectangle with diagonally opposite corners `(a, b)` and `(c, d)`. This can also be used for a square if `|a - c| = |b - d|`.

```
\node[star, star point height=xcm, minimum size=ycm, draw] at (a, b)
```

which draws a star centred at `(a, b)` with 'diameter' `y` measured in centimetres and point length `x` measured in centimetres.

```
\foreach \i in {start, next, ..., end} {
    % Something with \i
}
```

which loops over values of `\i` starting with `\i = start` then `\i = next` and incrementing `\i` in steps of `next - start` until `end` is reached. For example

```
\foreach {1, 3, ..., 9} {
    \draw (0, 0) circle [radius=\i cm];
}
```

draws circles centred on `(0, 0)` or radii 1, 3, 6, and 9.

The 12 star signs can be accessed from `marvosym` using `\Zodiac{n}` for `n=1,...,12`.

[image: basic magic circle]

Note that the bounding box is just from screen shotting the image, its not part of the drawing.

Useful Tikz resources:

- [The tikz manual](https://texample.net//media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf)
- [Tikz cheat sheet](https://faculty.cord.edu/ahendric/tex/TikZcheatsheet.pdf)
- [Examples of drawings](https://texample.net/tikz/)